# ¿Cómo poner los valores del eje y?

Tags: r, rstudio

Usé el siguiente comando:

```
ggplot(Edad, aes(x=Rango)) + 
   geom_bar(fill=color) + 
    labs(title="abejitas",x= "rango de edad", y= "Número de apicultores")
```

sin embargo, no entiendo porque los valores 4, 66 y 10 no me aparecen en el eje y.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el estadístico por defecto del `geom_bar()` es el `count` y solo tienes una observación por cada categoría, de ahí que cada barra tenga el mismo tamaño.

En tu caso, lo que puedes hacer es modificar el estadístico por `"identity"`, el cual básicamente asume que cada observación corresponde a una sola barra, pero necesitarás entonces "mapear" la variable que tiene el valor de `y`. Algo así:

```
library(ggplot2)
Edad <- data.frame(
  Rango = c('Rango 1', 'Rango 2', 'Rango 3'),
  Apicultores = c(1, 66, 10)
)
color <- c('Red', 'Blue', 'Green')
ggplot(Edad, aes(x=Rango, y=Apicultores)) + 
  geom_bar(fill=color, stat = "identity") + 
  labs(title="abejitas",x= "rango de edad", y= "Número de apicultores"
```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]